# Stop hyperlink inheriting div's width?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

Hi I have some hyperlinks  inside a div with display:block. Problem is that the hyperlinks length when clicked is equal to the div's width. How do I make the hyperlink's clicked length equal to the text of the hyperlink only without specifying width for each link ?
[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ByYCV/)

Comment: Is there a reason your links need `display:block`?

Comment: Emmett I am trying to avoid putting </br> tags in my markup to make each link on a new line ? Do you have any alternate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

`#links a {clear:left;float:left}`

The `float` will allow the link to be sized, and the `clear` will prevent the links from being on the same line.

You may need to add a `clear:left` to the `#links` container depending on your design.

**EDIT**

A little tutorial since you asked:

There are two types of elements, inline and block. Inline ones show in a line with no breaks.  Block elements take up the whole line and move to the next one.

Inline elements can't have their width or height styled.  Blocks can.

`<a>` is an inline element. By setting its display to block, you tell it to make a new line every time.

`float` gives elements inline behavior so they bump up next to eachother and flow over onto the next line. `float` also allows you to style the width/height of the element.  It's sort of a mix between the two.

The clear attribute stops the inline floating and goes back to normal block behavior (new lines every time).

You won't need `display:block` and `float:` at the same time.

Another solution would involve `display:inline-block`, but this is not supported in several browsers so isn't encouraged (although I find it pretty handy).

Comment: Thanks Steve =) that solved my problem. Is the clear attribute an alternate for display:block ? What is it supposed to do. Sorry I'm new with CSS.

Comment: @damien , if you say clear:left or clear:both , whatever items that are being left floated will be stopped. for example if you have three divs float:left , they will come side by side, after that if you say clear:left, the next div will come in the next line. if you say clear:both it willclear both left and right floats.

Answer (score 1):

set the link style to display:inline-block; (not supported in elder IE6) or float it with float:left; or float:right;

Comment: Thanks mister Olemarius. Do you know a way to make each hyperlink follow a new line without using display:block and </br> tags in markup ?

Comment: I think you can use clear:both; or clear:left/right (depending on which side of the element you want to clear).. Not 100% sure if it works on floated elements though..

Answer (score 1):

`display: block;` is what makes the link elements expand to their parent width. By default, link elements are in-line elements, not block elements.

Simply remove that declaration and your problem should be gone.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ByYCV/1/)

Comment: Hi FreekOne, can't we make each link come on a new line without using </br> tags ?

Comment: @Damien: Steve beat me to it :) Not sure what's wrong with using `<br>` tags though ...

Comment: Somebody told me that it looks unprofessional so I was trying to do it with CSS, but that's the easiest way round. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @Damien: Glad to be of help. I'm guessing that the same person uses `DIV` elements to simulate a table for tabular data, because using tables is also "unprofessional". Word of advice: if it's valid markup and it gets the job done, use it. It'll make your life a whole lot easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<a href="example.com" style="text-decoration: none;">Foo</a>
```

Comment: No, that's removing the underlining. What he wants is for the click box of the links to be the width of the link text.

Comment: Mister Sheffield please check my jsfiddle link. When you would click and hold on a link you will see the width is set to the div's width.

Answer (score 0):

width:auto?

Or try
display:inline;

on the links

it shouldnt get the divs width then