# Text <div> tags, and css

Tags: css, html, text

I have two questions:

1) I have a div with an image that I use for my footer, but I when I resize the page the footer text gets all "mushed" together. Is there any way I can get the text to stay in a certain position and resize with the page?

2) I use a div for the body of the page, but when I try to add text and align it in position it moves the entire div. How can I get the div (which is just background color) to stay in place while I move the text around?

Here is the site and code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HzwV9/embedded/result/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a fiddle with your fiddle, here's a result that may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/HzwV9/4/

Some things I noticed:

- A few of your HTML tags aren't closed (that's asking for trouble).
- No need to use `<h1>` for your lower links; [it's a block element, not an inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322029/stop-hyperlink-inheriting-divs-width/4322102#4322102), and also you'll need `<a>` to make a link later anyway
- You can simplify the big list of tags at the beginning by just using `*` - all!

Hope this helps.  Also, footers are notoriously difficult, since CSS [doesn't do vertical sizing very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931187/css-metaphysics-why-is-page-vertical-alignment-so-difficult)...there's a few solutions out there but they all have something wrong, up to you what you want to be wrong :)